# I have written col-md in my code, but i want to how to write for small device and large device

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-grid

I want to know how to write the code for col-sm smart phone device code  and right know i have written for desktop only,please check that also I am not sure about my coding, now only learning bootstrap, I am new to grid system and first site in bootstrap,Could any one help me, I always want to know in  practical experience.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8">
    <h3 class="title t-left">About <span>Lotus Interior</span></h3>
    <p style="text-align:justify; line-height:22px;">Lotus Value exemplifies purity and integrity. The symbolism guides us to be committed and transparent in all our dealings and adhere to timely delivery, ontime, each time,uncompromising on business ethics.We remain firmly committed towards creating urban living spaces where people can live,</p>
    </div> 
    <div class="col-md-4" style="padding-top:25px;">
    <img src="banner/banner5.jpg" alt="worker" class="img-responsive">
    </div> 
    </div>
    </div>


    <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3"><img src="row/1.jpg"/></div>
    <div class="col-md-3"> <img src="row/2.jpg"/></div>
    <div class="col-md-3"><img src="row/3.jpg"/></div>
    <div class="col-md-3"> <img src="row/4.jpg"/></div>
    </div>
    </div>
```

output image[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R2pVH.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends how large your images are and how many you would like next to each other.

On a mobile device you don't have much screen real estate, so the way you having 4 images next to each other in a single row will be too wide on a mobile device. I would recommend that you list them each 1 underneath each other for mobile so you would change your code as follow:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-3"><img src="row/1.jpg"/></div>
        <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-3"><img src="row/2.jpg"/></div>
        <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-3"><img src="row/3.jpg"/></div>
        <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-3"><img src="row/4.jpg"/></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The col-sm-12 advises that it should take up the entire row length, so with the above, on mobile it will list each image underneath each other.

Below is an example of your code for screen sizes for small, medium and large:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-3"><img src="row/1.jpg"/></div>
        <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-3"><img src="row/2.jpg"/></div>
        <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-3"><img src="row/3.jpg"/></div>
        <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-3"><img src="row/4.jpg"/></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

- On large devices(desktop): 4 images next to each other.
- On medium devices (tablets): 2 images next to each other, with the other two underneath.
- On small devices (mobile): 1 image with the others underneath

Give the following code a try, it creates a responsive image grid from the URL you provided an example of:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-3">
            <img class="img-responsive" style="margin-top: 10px; min-width: 100%" src="row/1.jpg"> 
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-3">
            <img class="img-responsive" style="margin-top: 10px; min-width: 100%" src="row/2.jpg"> 
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-3">
            <img class="img-responsive" style="margin-top: 10px; min-width: 100%" src="row/3.jpg"> 
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-3">
            <img class="img-responsive" style="margin-top: 10px; min-width: 100%" src="row/4.jpg"> 
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: please i upload to server i have another issue

Comment: Please explain the issue you are having. Can you provide me with a URL to the page?

Comment: please check now http://smclothingg.com/te1/ and help me out  there is no gap in image , please check in mobile and tell me for first container also it is not perfect in mobile,

Comment: if i want to add another four image in row two, what i have two, because my objective is total three row each row has four images,total 3 row and see also there is no image gap between each image for that which class element we have to use

Comment: but in tablet it is not reflecting what you said On medium devices (tablets): 2 images next to each other, with the other two underneath. please check that also

Comment: I updated the answer with the responsive image grid. Please try the code and let me know how that goes.

Comment: Here is a link to the full html page: https://gist.github.com/newtondev/d500284fc5109a4571255471009b33a9

Comment: Newton perfect one ,please check in online  http://smclothingg.com/te2/   on  tablet ,phones, but i want have a look on first container this one, col-md-8 and col-md-4 both are not reflecting properly in tablet and phone, please review that also, and educate me, and further i want create for labtop in a row four column  like first one Lotus Construction,2. Lotus Interior ,3.Lotus Digital,4.Lotus Site<div class="row"><div class="col-sm-12 col-md-3 col-lg-3">description here</div><div class="col-sm-12 col-md-3 col-lg-3">description </div>like this another 2 div</div> I hope u understood,help me

Comment: please check , I have tried with another container for above row with four column, please check and help me , is it correct or wrong http://smclothingg.com/te2/.  col-md-3 is correct or col-md-6 or col-md-4 but my objective is in a row four column text i want to make. and for sm and large deceive what i have to give.

Answer (score 0):

For small devices it is col-sm and for big devices it is col-sm and check the documentation it has everything!!

Comment: could use please give me the answer code so that i will check now itself, it tried that not reflecting in mobile device, where i have to add this code, i read the document, I am getting proper out that why